# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar Python en mi navegador?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache, servidor, python-2.x

Estoy buscando la manera más fácil y breve de poder ejecutar Python en mi navegador. Actualmente estoy utilizando Python 2.7, sin embargo no me gusta utilizar la consola y me gustaría poder programar en un IDE (Sublime Text).

En otras palabras, quiero ejecutar un script de Python como si fuera PHP.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <?php
       echo "Hello World!";
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso que necesito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python no hay soluciones del lado del servidor que usen Python de esa forma. Los *frameworks* más comunes como [Django Framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Pyramid](https://trypyramid.com/), usan otro tipo de implementación.

Voy a mencionar dos excepciones:

1. [Spyce](http://spyce.sourceforge.net/) fue diseñado para funcionar de forma parecida a PHP, pero su desarrollo se detuvo **hace más de diez años**,
2. [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) que al contrario de Spyce y de PHP no funciona del lado del servidor si no del cliente, como JavaScript. Lo que no deja de ser una curiosidad o un pasatiempo de los autores.

Comment: Entonces, ¿Cómo funciona Python? ¿Cómo hace obtiene los datos ingresados por el usuario? Estoy confundido :(

Comment: Hay cinco enlaces en mi respuesta, te sugiero que los revises. Intenta implementar alguno, que con excepción de Spyce, funcionan como se espera.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quiere hacer es ejecutar codigo on line 
http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

El IDE (Sublime Text) es muy bueno para comenzar a programar y de hecho yo lo uso y lo recomiendo, pero es off line y necesitas correr el programa cada vez que quieres verificar codigo

IPython es muy bueno  cito: IPython incluye además una versión en GNU/Linux para ser ejecutado en X y usando la biblioteca WX. En el uso de bibliotecas GUI, IPython no permite el bloqueo en la interacción con Tkinter, GTK+, Qt ni WX; solo permite la interacción con Tkinter. Ipython puede gestionar de forma interactiva el uso paralelo de varios clusters. IPython puede ser utilizado para reemplazar el shell de sistema gracias a lo flexible y modificable que es mediante su archivo de configuración, especialmente en windows. El shell de IPython recuerda a un shell de unix, e incluso permite usar comandos bash durante su uso para, por ejemplo, cambiar de directorio de trabajo

Como vez la mejor alternativa por lo que te entiendo es Ipython.

Comment: Aunque te recomiendo que veas la informacion de Jupiter vrs Ipython a ver que te funciona mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es un IDE en la nube te recomiendo:

- Cloud 9: https://c9.io/

Y si quieres un editor para tener snippets:

- http://code.runnable.com/

Comment: Quiere que Python funcione tal como funciona PHP... ninguna de las dos opciones sirve para eso.